# C++ iostreams and python

Tags: python, iostream, boost-python

Is it possible to interoperate with a C++ iostream and python? I'm using boost-python and want to wrap a function that has istream and ostream as arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is http://cci.lbl.gov/cctbx_sources/boost_adaptbx/python_streambuf.h what you are looking for? It comes from the Phenix project.

(license information at http://cci.lbl.gov/cctbx_sources/boost_adaptbx/LICENSE_2_0.txt)